# Limit of occupation times for Brownian motion

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion on $\mathbb R$ started at $0$. For $A\subset\mathbb R$ Lebesgue measurable, let $\mu_T(A) = \frac{1}{T} m(t \leq T: B_t \in A)$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Then $\mu_T$ is a random measure on $\mathbb R$. Do the random measures $\mu_T$ converge, in any reasonable sense, as $T\rightarrow \infty$? If so, what is the limit measure?

I know that the event that $\mu_T \rightarrow \mu$ for some fixed deterministic measure $\mu$ is a tail event (it is in the intersection of the $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(B_t : t \geq s)$). Therefore its probability is either 0 or 1. Beyond that, however, I do not have any real ideas as to how to approach this.

Comment: Show what you tried and the results you know that seem related to the question. (Amazing that after 17 months and 135 questions, you so squarely neglect the procedure...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mu_T(A)\to0$ for every bounded $A$.